# Storing all environment variables in one file

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables, path, profile

What are the caveats of having one single file with environment variables?

What I would like to do is to create a file (e.g. `~/.env`) which contains all necessary `PATH` declarations and possibly other non-confidential environment variables, such as `EDITOR` and `GOPATH`, and have this file sourced from within each of shell-specific dotfiles.

Specifically, I would want to include the line

```
    . "$HOME/.env"
```

to all `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zprofile`, `.zshenv`, `.zshrc`

The goal is to have a consistent behaviour of commands executed in interactive/non-interactive and login/non-login shells.

Why would I not want to do this? Are there any problems that may occur because of this?

---

I have read a bunch of answers on SE related to the topic such as

https://superuser.com/a/187673/924981
https://askubuntu.com/a/540689
https://askubuntu.com/a/866240
https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637979/3885799

and I understand what are some suggested practices of env declarations. However, I would like to know if the method above is also acceptable and safe.

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/a/183980/513541

Comment: consider what you've already read in the SU post: `The reason is that zsh has enough incompatibilities with standard shells to break scripts.`,  so any syntax you use has to be compatible with the shells you expect to source that file with.

Comment: it sounds like you're describing `/etc/environment`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, thank you. I do keep the syntax compatible.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Partially so. I could use `/etc/environment` in the same way and source it from everywhere, but on macOS I believe `/etc` is protected, and I would like to keep the file locally. The purpose would be the same though, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue with this is that if you source the file from both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, and if those two files source each other (and similarly for other shells), then you may source your environment file multiple (two) times when starting a shell session.

This is not an issue unless you *append*/*prepend* values to environment variables.

You could protect against this by setting a shell variable like `env_sourced` to some value in file and then testing it at the top:

```
# My environment file

[ -n "$env_sourced" ] && return
env_sourced=1

PATH="$PATH:/some/path"
# etc.
```

Comment: `#ifndef _MYHEADER_H` ...

Comment: @Bananguin Yes, it's an include guard, like what you would find in C headers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should not do this. For instance, I'm working in a mixed bash/zsh environment (i.e. I use in some terminal windows bash, and in some zsh). I put those definitions - environment variables, non-exported variables, shell functions -, which are syntactically compatible for both languages, in one common file, which I'm sourcing from .bashrc and from .zshrc.